# Protect PDF files to open in browser but allow download

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to protect all my PDF files.

For that, I add the following lines to .htaccess to prevent directory browsing:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Then, I created another .htaccess file inside wp-content folder and add this lines:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|svg)$">
   Allow from all
</Files>
```

Now I can't access PDF files directly. But I need a way to allow user click in links and download the files.

**UPDATE**

I tried with this snippet, but it caused error 500 in website:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|odf|pdf|rtf|txt)$">
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Error 500 solved by enabling Apache header module.

But now when I click in the link, the page return error 403 because my second snippet. Is there a way to avoid direct link and allow download?